# Out of memory while dropping a column

Tags: mysql

I've a database hosted on Clever-Cloud (https://www.clever-cloud.com/pricing - MySQL addon size LM: memory 1 GB & 2 vCPUS). I have a table with 188 000 lines about 311 MB using InnoDb engine.

When I try to drop a column of my table (no index on this column) I get in phpMyAdmin the following error:

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Log of MySQL at the time of the error : https://gist.github.com/urcadox/038c180cefdcba20e1052e7418a43324

I've read that InnoDb engine used memory to create a new table, copy the data without the dropped column and switch old and new tables to perform the drop operation.

- Is there anything I can do to use less memory?
- Is there anyway to make InnoDb use disk instead of memory?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question 100%, but to use less memory and disk, can you use B and B+ trees to organize records?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI That may work but I don't want to change the whole system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try ALGORITHM=COPY in in your table alteration query? It's is part of the [ALTER TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) It forces the table to be copied rather than be modified in place. It's memory usage is likely to be lower. But certain caveats apply

> Any ALTER TABLE operation run with the ALGORITHM=COPY clause prevents
>   concurrent DML operations. Concurrent queries are still allowed. That
>   is, a table-copying operation always includes at least the concurrency
>   restrictions of LOCK=SHARED (allow queries but not DML). You can
>   further restrict concurrency for such operations by specifying
>   LOCK=EXCLUSIVE, which prevents DML and queries.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try it early morning tomorrow (I'm in France!) while there is almost no one on the service